# FTP alias of home to the www dir

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, ftp, server

Created in ubuntu all the necessary configuration for access via FTP, but at one point I found a problem:

To restrict each user to only access to your /home/$USER but I want each user to access the folder /www/$DOMAIN

You can make an alias? Or alo for the same effect ... I tried a [**link**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/ln.1.html) but it gives an error and the connection goes down on FTP ...

Help: S

Answer (score 0):

Look at /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf if you've used this log
EDIT: Do you want the user both access www & home?

If you want your user to access /var/www/USER try ln -s /var/www/user /home/USER/www
and then in the proftpd.conf it'll look like ~/www

Comment: Hi, only to /home/www/domaintest...
/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf EDIT:
DefaultRoot                     ~